# Why do Perl's DBI placeholders break for negative number MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, perl, placeholder, dbi

I have two MySQL databases, numbers1 and numbers2, both look like this:

```
+--------+
| number |
+--------+
|     -5 |
+--------+
```

However, numbers1 has a VARCHAR column, whereas numbers2 has an INT column.

This code succeeds in printing "number is: -5" for numbers2, but fails for numbers1:

```
my $high_number = -2;
my $sql = "select * from numbers1 where number < ?";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($high_number);
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array){
        print "number is: $row[0]\n";
}
```

However, if I remove the placeholder and substitute directly:

```
my $sql = "select * from numbers1 where number < $high_number";
```

the code works just fine for both numbers1 and numbers2.

Thus, the culprit must be DBI's placeholders, which somehow break the mysql query for negative numbers (strangely positive numbers work just fine!)  Why do the DBI placeholders break for negative numbers here?

Note, this is the same problem as that encountered in this as yet [unsolved 2007 PerlMonks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=656378).

Comment: If you have a VARCHAR field, perhaps you should use a string, not a number, `my $number = "-2"`. Not that it should matter for Perl, but perhaps the DBI has something in their drivers that hard codes it. Can you for that matter do a `<` comparison on a varchar field?

Comment: Also, always include error messages. What error does DBI report?

Comment: Tried the string representation, no luck.  Yes you can do a < comparison on VARCHAR, because it works just fine in every other context.  The only time it breaks is when there's both a negative number and a placeholder.  Positive numbers with placeholders work fine.  Negative numbers substituted directly into the $sql string work fine.  DBI reports no errors.

Comment: If DBI reports no errors, how do you know something is wrong? "fails" is a pretty weak description of what is wrong.

Comment: Oh I see. When you say "fails", you mean it did not print anything. You should always be absolutely specific when describing your problem, in this case you should have said "It does not print anything", not "it fails".

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the future, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because MySQL is doing a string comparison, and the string "-5" is greater than the string "-3" even though the number -5 is less than the number -3. The behavior you are experiencing is expected, it is not "broken" as you claim.

When using a placeholder, the bound value is typecast to a string, because the column type is varchar. Your query without the placeholder has an integer on the right side. In other words, the two queries below will understandably yield different results:

```
select * from numbers1 where number < '$high_number';
select * from numbers1 where number < $high_number;
```

If you really want to do this, and want to use a placeholder, you could use explicit typecasting:

```
my $sql = "SELECT * FROM numbers1 WHERE 
           CAST(number AS SIGNED INTEGER) < CAST(? AS SIGNED INTEGER)";
```

Comment: That explains it.  Thank you for the awesome explanation!

Comment: or more tersely, `where number < round(?)`